# UnicodeEncodeError while installing ROS on Debian

Tags: ros-hydro, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to instal ROS hydro on a Debian system following the guide on the wiki.
When I executed:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/hydro
```

I got this error:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
Unhandled exception of type 'UnicodeEncodeError':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 832, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 585, in build_package
    destdir=destdir
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 378, in build_catkin_package
    if has_make_target(build_dir, 'install'):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 389, in has_make_target
    output = run_command(['make', '-pn'], path, quiet=True)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 208, in run_command
    out.write(line)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
Command failed, exiting.
```

Does anybody know what to do here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124081/unicodeencodeerror-while-installing-ros-on-debian/) by [josegaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/11416/josegaert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found an anwser:

It has something to to with using a different languages. For now, Japanese systems and French (mine) systems have found to give the bug. You can solve it by putting your system in English for a while.

```
root@xwzy:~/ros_catkin_ws# env | grep LANG
LANG=fr_BE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_BE:fr
root@xwzy:~/ros_catkin_ws# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
root@anoesjka:~/ros_catkin_ws# env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_BE:fr
```

And then it works.

---

Originally posted by [josegaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/11416/josegaert/) with karma: 56 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-30**:
For reference this is an open ticket which we haven't found a fix for yet: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/578